# Chrome createAttribute malforms prefix

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, exslt

I've got a simple piece of javascript that adds an exslt namespace to an xsl document.  However, Chrome and Firefox handle this differently.  Firefox will add the namespace correctly to the root with the full

`xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`

Chrome however just plunks in

`exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`

Did you see the difference?  '`xmlns`' is gone in the latter and Chrome itself thinks the xslt is malformed: it returns null when you transform! If you correctly prefix, i.e., `xmlns:exsl` and then Chrome likes it.  Try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bodyrock/1quo3dgk/4/) below with Firefox and then with Chrome to see the difference.  Here is the simple code

```
var styleString = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/"><div>hi</div></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>';
var xslDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(styleString, "text/xml");
var docRoot = xslDoc.documentElement;
a = document.createAttribute("xmlns:exsl");
a.nodeValue = "http://exslt.org/common";
docRoot.setAttributeNode(a);
var xmls1 = new XMLSerializer();
var outputXHtmlString = xmls1.serializeToString(xslDoc);
document.getElementById("content").innerText = outputXHtmlString;
```

Comment: can you try add this namespace on your xslt? var styleString = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"><xsl:template match="/"><div>hi</div></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>';

Comment: I'm adding the attribute dynamically with Javascript, so I appreciate the suggestion, but if hardcoding the namespace is the solution then I've got about 100 xsl files that  I need to modify.  In any event, I've forked the jsfiddle and I'll try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: after thinking about it, I'd rather hard code the namespace in the stylesheet.  That works in both Chrome and Firefox so I don't see a downside.  see it work here https://jsfiddle.net/bodyrock/0vtw8Lrs/23/

Comment: @EdBangga if you want to add your comment to the answer section I'll select it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 var styleString = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="exslt.org/common"><xsl:template match="/"><div>hi</div></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works in IE, Chrome and Firefox, but I discovered today that this doesnt work in Edge.  Edge still requires the hack, that is, you have to add EXSL via  document.createAttribute("xmlns:exsl"); if you hust hardcode it in the document as shown here then Edge throws an error 'Invalid Argument'